# Django Template -- How to insert and place a value in select box, on default?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am using django widget tweaks for displaying and tweaking my fields in django templates, every thing is working fine but for a select box when I render it, its initial displayed value is `-----`, where as I want to show my custom value instead of `-----`, like `--Select a Country--`
My syntax looks like this:

```
{{ form.countries }} // countries is a choice field, therefore it is displayed as a select box
```

If any change is required I do it like this:

```
{{ form.countries|attr:"class:span6" }} //just for an example
```

Please help me doing this,
I have tried this:

```
{{ form.countries|attr:"option:--Select a Country--" }}
```

Please help me out!
Editing would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done in the view where you initialize your form using the `initial` attribute.

So something like:

```
countries = forms.ChoiceField(
                choices=YourCountriesGoesHere, 
                initial='--- Select a country ---')
```

You can read the [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial)